# Display checkbox next to each listed item(error in code)

Tags: android

I have this code which is working to get all installed apps from android but now i want to display a checkbox next to each list item and get the items clicked into other activity. 
I have worked with normal strings and it appears to work properly when i use the code

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.simple_list_item_checked,    stringname));
```

But that is not working here as there is no string it could take. 
adapter variable from second line is a object so i cannot use that, so please tell me what I could do to add a checkbox next to each item.
Thanks.

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
AppAdapter adapter=null;
String[] apps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


ListView lstView = getListView();
lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);


PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
Intent main=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);

Collections.sort(launchables,
                 new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

adapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,
                             int position, long id) {

ResolveInfo launchable=adapter.getItem(position);
ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                     activity.name);
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
i.setComponent(name);

startActivity(i);
}

class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {
private PackageManager pm=null;

AppAdapter(PackageManager pm, List<ResolveInfo> apps) {
  super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, apps);
  this.pm=pm;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                      ViewGroup parent) {


  if (convertView==null) {
    convertView=newView(parent);
  }

  bindView(position, convertView);

  return(convertView);
}

private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
  return(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
}

private void bindView(int position, View row) {
  TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

  label.setText(getItem(position).loadLabel(pm));

  ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

  icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm));
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings :

        /*Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("key", adapter);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        break;*/
    }
    return false;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a layout like..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/check" 
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true">
    </CheckBox>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/label"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label"
        android:text="@+id/sub"
        android:textSize="15px" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here i use 2 textview and a checkbox for each list item of a listview.And later,in **onCreate()**:

```
            ls1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

            ls1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
                { 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

you can catch those list items id,but before you need to use **ViewHolder** to catch checked state of checkbox.A complete example would be this..

- [android-listview-checkbox-example.html](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)

Comment: Thanks but I have done that. I have worked with normal string variables and have successfully got the checkbox and sent it to another activity but I am unable to do that for the above code. I dont know where do I need to include the code for checked box. Thats where I am stuck

Comment: Okay I added a check box and now the 1st item has a check box but how do I add it to others?

Comment: it should be added each item list of listview,do't you follow the tutorial? There arraylist contains 7 items and see 7 checkbox added to corresponding list item.

Comment: no I didnt follow that. I couldnt get to know where seven checkboxes were added. sorry I am a newbie

Comment: Please could you tell where I need to add the code for checkbox? I tried adding it in bindView but it isnt working